# Submit form to another controller in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, design-patterns

I have a page `index.html.twig` which contains a `Form` this form when submitted, get validated and the result is shown in a page `success.html.twig`. Now I have a new requirement where the page `success.html.twig` itself contains a Form which should contain the values which were passed by the form from `index.html.twig` and if the user wants the new form should also allow the user to do search directly from `success.twig.html`. The requirement is inspired by [hostel world](http://hostelworld.com/).

**Questions**:

1. Is there a design pattern which I could use to implement a solution
2. My current thinking is to create a new Action for `success.html.twig` and submit the form to thatAction instead of rendering `success.html.twig` from `index.html.twig`'s Action. Is it correct? How can I implement it?

**Code (Partial)**:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $event = new Event();
    $form = $this->createForm(MyForm::class, $event);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $event->setPlace($form["place"]->getData());


        $event->setDate($form["date"]->getData()->modify('+12 hours'));
        return $this->render('default/frontend/success.html.twig',
            array('events' => $events, 'cityName' => $cityName, 'cityImage' => $cityImage)
        );
    }

    return $this->render('default/frontend/index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: I think creating a new action for success is correct. At the form creation, you can try this : `$form =$this->createForm(new Event(), $event);`. So you populate your new form with the value your receive from `indexAction`

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to have two different actions - at least for different request types (GET, POST, etc..)

There is just one thing as advice: `$form->isValid()` has already an `isSubmitted()` check inside. So there is no need to check whether it is submitted or not.

Comment: But currently the index.html.twig's action is the one which after the form is submitted renders success.html.twig. how can I call the success.html.twig's action once created? Currently I have no action for success.html.twig

Comment: Please be aware that calling `isValid()` for an unsubmitted form will not be supported anymore as of Symfony 4.0 (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.2.md#form). So calling `isSubmitted()` first is indeed the right way.

Comment: You can tell your form to use a certain action to submit your request  against - default would be the same action.

e.g. $this->createForm(
           MyForm::class,
            $event,
            $options
        );

While $options could be ['action' => '/some/other/url or route', 'method' => 'POST']

@xabbuh thx for the advice.. didn't know.